# error in the command : $ionic cordova platform add android

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

```
ionic cordova platform add android
[WARN] Detected locally installed Ionic CLI, but it's too old--using global CLI.
> cordova.cmd platform add android
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@^8.0.0
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
        Path: platforms\android
        Package: com.ionicframework.facetsapp
        Name: Facets
        Activity: MainActivity
        Android target: android-28
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Android project created with cordova-android@8.1.0
Source path does not exist: resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd platform add android exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more
        information.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `ionic cordova resources` 
If no changes, post your `ionic info`

Comment: You can try to  add ionic cordova resources -f, to force the generator. Although i nevver could do it on windows. it always get stuck in some image. What i did, was to find a project, and download the resources myself. If you want to add your icon, you'll have to edit the images one by one. On macOs, that command works fine for me